# Adding a class name in html, using php outputted extra '/' on live site, but not on local

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is my scenario, I am creating an html class using php, everything is working fine on my local website, but when its online it has extra '/' character, i cant figure out, what causes this.

Any help would be greatly appriaciated, thanks.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="category-name-container">
    <span class="circle x3 <?='sub-category-'.$subcategory_slug;?> sub-category-color"></span>
    <p><?=$name;?></p>
</div>
```

Output local:

[image]

Live output, notice the extra '/' being created!!!
[image]

Comment: How do you retrieve the value for $subcategory_slug? The slash is in there.